How to save a webpage as .mhtml with Firefox?
Is there any way to save a webpage as an .mhtml file using a current Firefox version? If yes, please provide detailed instructions.
I have done a lot of web search and found no way to do it. I am willing to install Firefox addons for this task, if required.

What research have you done and what have you tried so far attempting to do this?

I don't know how to answer this boilerplate question. I have done a lot of web search. And I have not found any way to save a webpage as .mhtml using Firefox (otherwise I obviously would not have asked the question), so the second half of your question does not apply, because I didn't find any method to "attempt".

Found a duplicate which has answers that are still valid: https://superuser.com/questions/1365601/how-to-open-mht-files-on-firefox-58  MHT files have not been supported by FF. MHT is largely an IE-only format that has died since the death of that browser. I believe Chrome MAY support it, but if you're looking for a single-file package of a web page, PDF may be your best option these days.


Is there any way to save a webpage as an .mhtml file using a current Firefox version?

No, there is not. Firefox has not supported MHT/MTHML since the release of Firefox 57 (Quantum). There are no addons that support this because the WebExtensions API is more restrictive than what the older extensions used and does not allow the access to all of the resources needed.
If you need to save a page as a single file, you can try the addon Save Page WE.
You can voice your support for this feature here: https://connect.mozilla.org/t5/ideas/add-native-web-archive-file-support-to-firefox-including-mhtml/idi-p/37324
